# Space above slides_container in slidesjs jquery slideshow carousel - css

Tags: jquery, html, css, slideshow

I've implemented http://slidesjs.com/ on a new website.

I am getting 2 pixels space above slides_container in IE8. Can anyone tell me why? Is it in the CSS? the Javascript?

The test site is here: http://www.doublebdiner.com/

FYI, I am the builder only, not the designer.

Please let me know if you would like me to post code here.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On `#tabnav`, remove the `height: 45px` rule.

It's creating the "space" you're talking about, because the number `45` is a little too large. `43` would work better, but there's no need to declare a `height`, so removing the rule is the best plan.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I removed that rule (updated at URL given), but unfortunately the space is still there. When I use Firebug to highlight elements, it seems like the slides_containter element is offset 2 pixels down from the parent element.

Comment: Wait wait, it did work! I was updating a backup copy of the CCS file. Sorry for that. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: My mind was so focused on the slider code, I had blinders on. It's always good to take a step back and look at the big picture, at how surrounding elements can affect another element.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be the #tabnav 45px height.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I removed that rule (updated at URL given), but unfortunately the space is still there.